# How many times function executes inside for loop?

Tags: javascript

My question is simple if I have a `for` loop and I had a function inside it, how many times will the function execute.

eg:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   console.log(i);
   (function(i){
      console.log(i)
   })
}
```

If anyone has the answer can you please explain to me why? 
Thanks in advance.

What about this case:

```
for (k=0; k<5;k++) {
$( '#a_' + k ).on('click', function() {
console.log("Clicking on a_" + k)
});
}
```

so when if I pass id as a_1, what will be the console print.

Comment: 0,1,2  After that "i" is not less than 3 anymore; if the function is changing the value of "i", then only you know.

Comment: As many times as the loop executes.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't think so when executed in the console the function only executed at the end of 0,1,2

Comment: You never *execute* the `(function(i){ console.log(i) })` it's just a function expression that defines an anonymous function. However, if you did, then it'd be executed once per loop.

Comment: oh okay, so my function will execute as many times as the loop iterates.

Comment: If you execute it, then yes.

Comment: lemme update my question stay with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209725/discussion-between-user12551649-and-vlaz).

Comment: For your second question, it depends on if you use a `var` or a `let`

Comment: I read this whole discussion but I still don't understand as of why would my code print out value as a_5 even thou the condition is matched at a_1

Comment: Because by the time the click handler runs “k” will be 5, in other words, the value that causes the loop to exit.

Comment: @user12551649 The first thing you **must** understand is that adding a click handler, by using `button.on('click', some_function)`, the function is **not** executed immediately. It gets executed when you click the button, and uses the current value of `k` when that happens. If `k` was changed between the time you added the click function and the time you clicked the button, the click function uses the *new* value, not the *old* value. When you write a loop using `k=0`, it declares one single global variable, and then changes that same variable each iteration - it will be `5` after the loop.

Comment: Then all click handlers refer to that one `k` variable, whose value is now `5`.

Comment: @Klaycon But it also depends on scope, if the op uses `let` it will print `0,1,2,3,4` but if it's a `var`, it will print `5,5,5,5,5`.

Comment: Yeah cuz then let won't be global and only have block scope, whereas var variables have  global scope

Comment: @Keith Right, I forgot to specify that too. The goal is to make a different `k` in each iteration (using `let`) rather than reusing the same one (`var` or globals). You can also ensure you capture a different variable using an IIFE if needed. @user12551649 `var` variables have function scope, not global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the function runs 0 times. You have a function expression, but you never call it. To call it you need to add `(<argument>)` after the expression.

```js
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   console.log(i);
   (function(i){
      console.log(i+10)
   })(i)
}
```

In the second code snippet, all the buttons will log `Clicking on a_5`.  Closures contain a reference to the variable, not a snapshot of its value when they were created. All the closures refer to the same `k` variable, and at the end of the loop it will be set to `5`. So they all concatenate `5` to the log message.

See [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue) and [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for a detailed explanation and solutions.

Comment: Hey can u explain to me with my example, helps me understand better.

Comment: I've added more details about the reason and a link to another question.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function inside the for loop won't execute at all. It would have to be an immediately invoked function expression to get executed.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   console.log(i);
   (function(i){
      console.log(i)
   })(i); // pass (i) as argument to execute
}
```

What you had previously will never execute:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   console.log(i);
   (function(i){
      // will never execute because this is function is never invoked
      console.log(i)
   })
}
```